# LookupOrderedRows returning only 2000 records in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there any workaround to retrieve more than 2000 records through LookupOrderedRows. I have the DE with over 100000 (100k, 1lakh) records.

```
%%[ 

var @companyrows1, @rowCNT

Set @companyrows1 = LookupOrderedRows('testcompname',0,'companyname ASC','ID','1234')

set @rowCNT = rowcount(@companyrows1)
output(%%=v(@rowCNT)=%%)

]%%
```

Comment: Why do you want to returning 100k rows with AMPscript?

Answer (score 4):

To combine both @AdamSpriggs and @BradSapkota's answers, you can use the DataExtensionRowCount() inside the LookUpOrderedRow() Function to ensure you always can pull the maximum rows of that DE if required.

For example:

`Set @companyrows1 = LookupOrderedRows('testcompname',DataExtensionRowCount('testcompname'),'companyname ASC','ID','1234')`

This will return all rows that match your where statement, up to a total of the Rowcount of the Data Extension you are pulling from.

Now, keep in mind running Lookups with significant sized returns can greatly reduce efficiency and potentially slow down your processing enough to time out or cause errors. So use this option cautiously. I also would avoid using it inside any sendable environments.

Comment: Thanks Gortonington for the formula. It worked after adding the total count in the LookupOrderedRows.

Answer (score 2):

As per my quick test on CloudPage, I ran `LookUpOrderedRows` for about 1 million rows and I was able to get a million rows, however, the ideal limit is 2000 rows as per the documentation, also, the function defaults to 2000 rows for the performance reasons.

Here is how you'd do it.

```
%%[
VAR @companyrows1, @rowCNT
SET @companyrows1 = LookupOrderedRows('testcompname',1000000,'companyname ASC','ID','1234')
SET @rowCNT = rowcount(@companyrows1) output(%%=v(@rowCNT)=%%)
]%%
```

Reference: [**LookUpOrderedRows**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the rowcount, then why not just use the [**DataExtensionRowCount**](https://ampscript.guide/book/dataextensionrowcount/) function?

```
%%[

var @rowCount
set @rowCount  = DataExtensionRowCount("testcompname")

]%%
rowCount: %%=v(@rowCount)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. it worked now I requirement was to pull the whole records to for kind of predictive intelligence search in the textbox. so was checking the recordcount. The code I have used is below,

Comment: LookupOrderedRows('testcompname',100000,'companyname ASC','ID','1234')